# .on('click','handler' function(){})

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте!

при вызове данных по AJAX необходимо использовать

```
$(document).on('click','handler' function(){})
```

но работает всё (dblclick, hover...) кроме 'click'!

В чём проблема?

Comment: приведите пример неработающего кода. запятая случайно пропущена?

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-trigger', function () {   
        alert('w');
    });

Comment: и где `'.ui-datepicker-trigger'`?

Comment: Сайтик большой. Этот класс встречается в разных местах. Но всега стоит рядом с input обёрнутые в div. По нажатию по нему вызывается календарик из бэка asp.net. Задача отменить это нажатие и задать своё. $(document).off('click', '.ui-datepicker-trigger');
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-trigger', function () {
    alert('w');
});

Comment: ах да. .off тоже не работает

Comment: Для лучшей производительности вашего приложения необходимо располагать обработчик как можно ближе к элементу от которого начинается всплытие события. И необходимо избегать использование элементов document или document.body при делегировании события. Попробуйте вместо document $('.ui-datepicker-trigger', handler).on('click', function () { alert('w'); });

Comment: Никак. Самое интересное если в Chorme watch добавить $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').unbind('click'); то всё замечательно. добавляю то же самое в код и тишина

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так заработало без вопросов. почему напрямую нельзя было Unbind сделать - непонятно

```
$(document).on('hover', '.ui-datepicker-trigger', function () {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        alert('s');
    })
})
```

Comment: скорее всего потому, что когда ты пытался сделать unbind нужного элемента еще не было

Comment: похоже на правду